# Computing the $K$-theory of the free inverse semigroup $C^*$-algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras

A typical example where I know the $K$-theory of the quotient, and wonder if this could help to compute the $K$-theory of the extension. (Or other way round: knowing one part out of three ones.)

I have a certain exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow J \rightarrow F \rightarrow F/J \rightarrow 0$$
of $C^*$-algebras. I put it into the $K$-theory cyclic exact sequence and get
$$
\begin{matrix} K_0(J) & \rightarrow & K_0(F) & \rightarrow & \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}\\
\uparrow & && & \downarrow^{\bf 0}\\
0 & \leftarrow & K_1(F)& \leftarrow & K_1(J)
\end{matrix} $$

Hence
$$K_1(F) = K_1(J)$$
$$K_0(F)/K_0(J) =  \bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$$

> Any idea how to compute $K_i(F)$?

Here, $F$ is the universal $C^*$-algebra of the free inverse semigroup generated by $n$ generators $s_1, \ldots, s_n$,
and $J$ is the two-sided closed ideal of $F$ generated by the relations
$$s_i s_i^* s_j s_j^* \quad \forall 1 \le i \neq j \le n$$
(range projections of the generators are orthogonal).

Similarly one has
$$
\begin{matrix} K_0(I) & \rightarrow & K_0(F) & \rightarrow & \mathbb{Z}_{n-1}\\
\uparrow & && & \downarrow^{\bf 0}\\
0 & \leftarrow & K_1(F)& \leftarrow & K_1(J)
\end{matrix} $$
because of the exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow F \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_n \rightarrow 0$$
for the Cuntz algebra $\mathcal{O}_n$.

> Does such information help for the computation of $F$ or is it unpromisingly if you know only one algebra out of three ones?